# Will every subset of $R$ that is not bounded above contains a sequence that diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

**Question:**

(a) Prove that every subset of $R$ that is not bounded above contains a sequence that diverges to infinity.

(b) Prove that every unbounded subset of $R^d$ contains a sequence ($x_n$) with the property that $\lim_(n_\to ∞_)$ ||($x_n$)|| = $∞$

**Idea:**

Consider a non-empty subset $A$ and a sequence ($a_n$). For part a), since the subset is not bounded above, then

there exist a number t such that $a ≥ t$ for all a $\in$ $A$.

the supremum of $A$ does not exist.

it diverges to  ∞ and the $lim sup$ ($A$) does not exist as well.

These are the things that I can conclude from the given, but I am not 100% sure that all of them are correct. I am trying to find some connection between the subset and its sequence, so that I can prove since the subset diverges to infinity, then the sequence also diverges to infinity. However, I am not sure if I am in the right track. Should I prove this by contradiction?

For part b), I started by listing the definition as well, but I don't know how to continue after I list the definitions.

Any help will be super appreciated, Thanks

Let me know if the context is not readable.

Comment: Your statement "then there exist a number $t$ such that $a\ge t$ for all $a\in A$ does not follow from the assumption that $A$ has no upper bound. For example, it is false if $A=\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use the integers, which we know diverge to infinity. If $A$ is not bounded above, we construct a sequence $(a_n)$ with $a_n\in A$ for all $A$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=\infty$. We ensure this by constructing the sequence such that $a_i>i$ for all $i$. This can be done independently for each $i$: given that $i$ is not an upper bound of $A$, there exists an $x\in A$ such that $x>i$; set $a_i=x$. (This is really invoking the axiom of choice since there are infinitely many arbitrary choices).

Comment: I didn't notice part b was multidimensional, but a very similar construction will work.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. What is the relationship between subset and sequence? Does a subset contain a lot of sequences?

Comment: Also, this may be a silly question but why is ($a_i$) > $i$?

Comment: @Joy a sequence is actually a function whose domain is the index set, while a subset is just a subset. $a_i>i$ because I made sure to pick a point larger than $i$ (though I didn't specify exactly which one, one must exist since $i$ is not an upper bound).

Comment: @Joy $(a_i)$ is lazy notation for the entire sequence, $a_i$ is an element in the sequence, and $i$ is the index, which is an integer.

Comment: Could you please check this to see if I understand correctly. $a_i$ is a term in a sequence and $i$ s a number, you pick $a_i$> $i$ because you want to make sure there will always be a number in this sequence that is greater than $i$. Does this mean I need to start my sequence from $a_0$? If my sequence is {1,2,3,4,.....} where $a_0$ = 1. If $i$  equals to 1, then $a_1$ >1 is true since $a_2$ is 2 and it is greater than 1.

Comment: @Joy you can't just pick any point you want. They have to be points in $A$. Since you don't know what $A$ is, you can't pick a particular point.

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot1

Comment: @Joy no problem

Answer (score 1):

For  (b):Let $f(1)=1$. Let $f(n+1)>f(n) $ such that $|a_{f(n+1)}|>1+|a_{f(n)}|.$ By induction on $n$ we have $|a_{f(n)}|\geq n+|a_1|.$ For (a):Let $f(1)=1$ and let $f(n+1)>f(n)$ such that $a_{f(n+1)}>a_{f(n)}.$ By induction on $n$ we have $a_{f(n)}\geq n+a_1.$

Comment: Thanks a lot. How did you know that this question can be done by induction? I mean, I was trying to prove by definition and I think I would never think about proving this by induction if you didn't tell me.

Comment: It's a common approach for q's like this.The idea is that, for (a), given $x_{f(n)}$ there is $f(n+1)>f(n)$ with $x_{f(n+1)}$ much bigger than $x_{f(n)}.$  So,  we  can easily  get $x_{f(n+1)}>1+x_{f(n)}.$ This  is sufficient to ensure that the sequence $(x_{f(n})_n$ is unbounded. It would not be enough to only have $x_{f(n+1)}>x_{f(n)}$.

Comment: Thank you so much @user254665 !